# Where or when should a php framework be called when using docker?

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, frameworks

We need to create an api that will be deployed in a docker container. This api will be created using a php framework (apiplatform). I am wondering where the framework should be placed in the overall process. I don't know if any of the following would make sense, thanks for any hint on what should(n't) be done !

Should we build a docker image just for the framework, based on the required dependencies (php, composer, nginx for example), and then use this image as a base for the api code (and then build an image for the api, that will be deployed as a container); or should the framework AND the api code live together in the same image and then be deployed in the same container ?

The benefits i see with the first option would be to strictly separate the api from the main dependencies, so that all developers on the team would only be focus on the logic of the api; a member of the team would then be designated as the "framework maintainer". But we would need to build everything again when the framework is updated, right ?

Is this a nonsense ? Because on the various examples i've seen, the developers are building an image containing the required dependencies for the framework, and then use this image as a base to install the framework, then develop the code for their app. I was wondering if there was a way to "pack" the framework and its dependencies first, and use it as a base image. I guess there's something i'm missing !

Comment: Your question will probably get closed because it's opinion-based. With that said, if you're making microservices, then each service should be able to be deployed without forcing the other services to also be deployed. Your framework sounds like it's like a package that is used by your services and those are usually updated whenever the service that uses it updates. If you need all your services to update at the same time when your framework updates, then you might just as well make a (well-structured) monolith and deploy all your code at the same time.

Comment: API Platform sells itself as a full stack framework, and it also encourages you to install the Symfony framework, or bring your own. For the latter two, we're often talking about the public-facing, as well as the admin/CRUD stuff. I just want to be clear on nomenclature. My recommendation is to build a single install first, and worry about separating things if/when the need arises.

Comment: How many network endpoints will you have?  Would it make sense to make an HTTP request to "only the framework" separately from "the API"?  If so then two containers would make sense, but if as @ChrisHaas suggests they always go together and "the framework" is a means to serve "the API", then it would usually need to be just one.